# Could any one explain me why this error was occuring while doing in IO operations?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, permissions, file-permissions

I have a small windows app which was given in this [article](http://justlikeamagic.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/programmatically-compress-and-decompress-files/.).

In this I want to to compress a sample.txt file.
But am getting this error:

> "Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\hemanth.vemu\Desktop\Compress' is denied."

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says.

The account that the application is running under does not have the right permissions on the folder in question.

Make sure you have read/write/create permissions on the folder you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give your application authentication to the `hemanth.vemu` user. You can use `LogonUser` to do this. It can validate both local and remote users. For local users simply pass the machine name in place of the domain.